# How do I concatenate two dataframes in R where neither table has a unique id column?

Tags: r, dataframe, join

I have two dataframes (df1 and df2) in R that I am trying to join. Neither have the same unique column, but they do both share a name column. Here is a snippet of each data frame:

df1:

| name | sale_id | sale_amnt | product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 03782 | 200 | tech |
| Max | 87367 | 85 | clothes |
| Beth | 63624 | 50 | home |
| Max | 01873 | 500 | tech |
| Jeff | 98077 | 300 | home |
| Jeff | 87321 | 100 | clothes |

df2:

| name | state | region |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | WI | USA |
| Max | CA | USA |
| Beth | CO | USA |
| Jeff | NA | Canada |

This is the data frame that I am trying to create:

df3:

| name | sale_id | sale_amnt | product | state | region |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 03782 | 200 | tech | WI | USA |
| Max | 87367 | 85 | clothes | CA | USA |
| Beth | 63624 | 50 | home | CO | USA |
| Max | 01873 | 500 | tech | WI | USA |
| Jeff | 98077 | 300 | home | NA | Canada |
| Jeff | 87321 | 100 | clothes | NA | Canada |

I tried using an outer join but that did not work. What should I be doing instead?

Comment: Columns don't have to be unique to join. This can be come with a standard merge/join: `merge(df1, df2)`. Since they both have a column named "name", that will be used for joining.

Comment: I tried merge(df1, df2) but it just returns an empty df3 with all of the headers from df1 and df2

Comment: That that means none of the values in the `name` column matched exactly. Did you actually use the data above in the example? If we can't replicate the problem it's very difficult to help. Please share a `dput()` of your data objects rather than these tables because the `dput` will show how the data is stored in R. You can see more at [how to make a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thank you for the comment! There were added spaces in df2. Problem solved